# Value is a duplicate in Altium Designer BOM

Tags: altium, bom

I'm using ActiveBOM in Altium Designer 19.  My design has 100k 5% resistors and also has 100k 1% resistors.  ActiveBOM gives an informational warning (an "i" with a white circle around it) that the value 100k is a duplicate.  I'd like to clear this error.

I'd guess there's a way to suppress this error in Project Options, but I don't want to do that because finding duplicate parts is a good feature.

I could also change the 'Value' field of one of the parts, but that doesn't seem right because they both actually are 100k.

I guess I could change my use of the resistor value field to include the tolerance, but that seems like it might mess up simulation (which I haven't started using yet).

What's the best way?

Comment: This doesn't tell you how to clear the error directly but the cost of 1% vs. 5% resistors (well, 100k resistors) is small, and a quick look shows that the 1% parts can actually be *cheaper* than the 5% parts.

Comment: @PeterSmith That's a good point, but I have a similar issue in other places where that substitution doesn't make sense: like a 10k resistor and a 10k thermistor, a 5% resistor and a 0.01% resistor, ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In BOM Checks, click the "gear" icon, set "duplicate value" to "No report"

Answer (score 0):

Some are mentioned above, there are a couple of options here:

- Suppress reporting of the error, which can hide useful warnings too
- Combine the parts, where applicable.  This is good design (and cost-savings) practice too.
- Use different part designator letters.  For example use "R" for a 10k resistor and "TR" for a 10k thermistor
- Include the tolerance (or whatever the necessary difference is) in the value field:  2 resistors could be "1k 5%" versus "1k 0.01%"

Comment: How do you "combine the parts"?

Comment: @topher217 Just decide that they are identical and always use the first one and don't use the 2nd.